# customer wants create nodepool with higher configuration but in that subscription not showing all vm sizes for zones

Tags: azure-aks

He is  using 2 subscriptions with 2 different clusters one subscription showing all VM sizes all zones but another subscription showing all VM sizes in zone 1 only why not showing remaining 2 zones

Can please go through question can you explain with solution in Azure portal

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First verify whether the VM sizes you are looking for are indeed available in all three availability zones of the region in the subscription that shows only Zone 1. Not all VM sizes are available in all zones also Ensure that you are selecting the correct Azure region and availability zone when provisioning or viewing VM sizes. Each region has its own set of available sizes and zones.